# menu expands a little to the right

Tags: html, css, menu, expand

My menu is expanding a little to the right, and i can't find the cause. I am new to coding.

If i put the #nav ul ul position to relative, it expands the menu cell, if i put it to absolute i doesn't do that, but the menu appears under the next menu cell.

this is my .HTML

```
<div id="navWrap">
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="smoothScroll">Home </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                <li><a href="#" class="smoothScroll">Meniu 1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sm1.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sm1.2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sm1.3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="smoothScroll">Meniu 2 </a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sm2.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sm2.2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sm2.3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="smoothScroll">Meniu 3 </a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub meniu 3.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub meniu 3.2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub meniu 3.3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="smoothScroll">Meniu 4 </a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub meniu 4.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub meniu 4.2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub meniu 4.3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="smoothScroll">Meniu 5 </a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub meniu 5.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub meniu 5.2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub meniu 5.3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="smoothScroll">Meniu 6 </a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub meniu 6.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub meniu 6.2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub meniu 6.3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <br class="clearleft"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is my .CSS

```
#navWrap {
height:30px;
background:#0d364c;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
width:705px;
}

#nav {
padding:5px;
margin:0px;
background:#0d364c;
height:25px;
font-size:15px;
width:700px;
}

#nav ul {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px ;    
   list-style: none;
   position: relative;
   display: block;
}

#nav ul:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both; 
    display: block;
}

#nav li {
   padding:5px 0px;
   background-color: #0d364c;
   margin: 0 0 0 0;
   color: #FFF;
   list-style-type: none;
   border-right: 1px solid #fff;
   display:inline;
   font-family:sans-serif;
   height:30px;
   width:70px;
}

#nav li:last-child{
border-right:none;
}

#nav li a {
   color: #FFF;  
   text-decoration: none;    

}

#nav li a:hover {
   text-decoration: underline; 
   background:#577283;
}

#nav ul ul {
display:none;
border-radius: 0px; 
padding: 2px;
position: absolute; 
height:30px;
background:black;
top:30px;
}

#nav ul  li:hover>ul{
display:inline-table;
float:none;
}

#nav ul li:hover{
background:#577283;
}

#nav ul ul li {
    position: relative;
    float:none;
    border:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:70px;
}

#nav ul ul li a {
    display: block; 
    text-decoration: none;
    height:40px;
    width:70px;
    color: white;
    background:gray;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 1px;    
}
```

here is my JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tHUWc/

Thank you, Iosif

Comment: Not really clear what items are you referring

Comment: @Itay close it as unclear :)

Comment: @Itay It is obvious that he is refering to the dropdown menu.... When you hover it instead of dropping down right under the hovered element it goes under the one next to it.

Comment: Using Firefox 23 with Windows 7 all the menus appear on the left, not on the right... if I got the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `#nav li { position: relative; }` and `#nav ul ul { left: 0; }`

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/tHUWc/2/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using float. I fixed the "expanding to the right" by floating the `#nav`

See this example http://jsfiddle.net/monnoval/tHUWc/3/